# Is it possible for GCP's "Metrics explorer" to aggregate within a fixed time range instead of the rolling window?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

Is it possible for GCP's "Metrics explorer" to aggregate within a fixed time range instead of the "rolling window"?

I want to monitor the API consumption to make sure it does not reach the Quota. Then, when the limit is approached, I want to set up an alert policy in order to take measures such as applying for relaxation of the limit or reducing usage.

Let's say I have the following data points

| datetime | API request count |
| --- | --- |
| August 1, 10:00 | 1 |
| August 1, 15:00 | 1 |
| August 1, 20:00 | 1 |
| August 2, 01:00 | 1 |
| August 2, 06:00 | 1 |

Since the API Quota is reset at 0:00 every day, I want to monitor the sum of consumption from 0:00 on one day to 0:00 on the next day. For example, I want to observe "3" as the usage on August 1, and "2" as the usage on August 2.

However, the period of aggregation in GCP's Metrics explorer seems to be "Rolling window" only. In that case, for example, "4" at 02:00 on August 2 and 5" at 09:00 on August 2 will be observed.

Comment: Your API count is not getting to 0  after every  24 hours. You have to reset it. Here are some docs [Capping API Usage](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage) and [Filtering and Aggregation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/aggregation)  which can be helpful. Do let me know if your problem was solved or not?

Comment: Thank you. But not solved yet. API usage is just an example. I want to know how to create fixed window metrics.

Comment: have you checked those docs? was anything helpful?